# I am getting a empty string for my function's return value

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting a empty string when I try to use my function's return value in another function. I declared the function value as variable so I am not sure why I am getting that.

```js
const fnCalIn = calIn();
const fnCalOut = calOut();

//to get the value in the calIn input field and turn it into a number then print to page
function calIn() {
  var calIn = document.getElementById("calIn").value;
  var clCalIn = Number(calIn);
  document.getElementById("demo-1").innerHTML = clCalIn;
  return clCalIn;
};

//to get the value in the calOut input field and turn it into a number then print to page
function calOut() {
  var calOut = document.getElementById("calOut").value;
  var clCalOut = Number(calOut);
  document.getElementById("demo-2").innerHTML = calOut;
  return calOut;
};

// Where I want to get the difference of the calOut and calIn values and print that to the page
function calDt() {
  var clCalDt = fnCalOut - fnCalIn;
  document.getElementById("calDt").innerHTML = clCalDt;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="current">Today</h1>
<div>
  <h3>Calories in </h3>
  <input id="calIn">
  <button onclick="calIn()">Get value</button>
  <p id="demo-1"></p>
</div>

<div>
  <h3>Calories Out </h3>
  <input id="calOut">
  <button onclick="calOut()">Get value</button>
  <p id="demo-2"></p>
</div>

<div>
  <h3>Deficit </h3>
  <div>
    <p id="calDt"></p>
    <button onclick="calDt()">Get value</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I keep getting a 0 When I change the HTML to clCalDt, I should get some value depending on what I enter in my input field but I get nothing. And when I try logging the values I get an empty string "".

Comment: Try `var clCalDt = calOut() - calIn();` 
(When you assign `const fnCalIn = calIn();` in the beginning, you're assigning the *result* of the function, not the function itself.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling the functions (fnCalIn and fnCalOut) only once at the beginning and then their values remain static and any changes in the page don't affect them. Try changing

```
var clCalDt = fnCalOut - fnCalIn;
```

to:

```
var clCalDt = calOut() - calIn();
```

in order for the values to be re-calculated.

Comment: This ^ 

There is no need to set the functions to a variable (first lines) since `calOut` and `calIn` are already variable names for the functions

Comment: @Rashsmit the answer is yes! In general it's preferred to use let/const than using var.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues.  You were returning return calOut; and not return clCalOut, and in the calculation you need to call the functions.  Might want to check to make sure then entry is actually a number somewhere.

```js
//to get the value in the calIn input field and turn it into a number then print to page
function calIn() {
  var calIn = document.getElementById("calIn").value;
  var clCalIn = Number(calIn);
  document.getElementById("demo-1").innerHTML = clCalIn;
  return clCalIn;
};

//to get the value in the calOut input field and turn it into a number then print to page
function calOut() {
  var calOut = document.getElementById("calOut").value;
  var clCalOut = Number(calOut);
  document.getElementById("demo-2").innerHTML = calOut;
  return clCalOut;
};

// Where I want to get the difference of the calOut and calIn values and print that to the page
function calDt() {
  var clCalDt = calOut() - calIn();
  document.getElementById("calDt").innerHTML = clCalDt;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="current">Today</h1>
<div>
  <h3>Calories in </h3>
  <input id="calIn">
  <button onclick="calIn()">Get value</button>
  <p id="demo-1"></p>
</div>

<div>
  <h3>Calories Out </h3>
  <input id="calOut">
  <button onclick="calOut()">Get value</button>
  <p id="demo-2"></p>
</div>

<div>
  <h3>Deficit </h3>
  <div>
    <p id="calDt"></p>
    <button onclick="calDt()">Get value</button>
  </div>
</div>
```